# JQuery select HTML element that matches given condition, and change its CSS style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to HTML, CSS and Jquery (probably English too). I have a list of products like this (the tags are just figurative):

```
<product id="product-1">
    <thumbnail>
        <img>
        <!-- This product does not have the out-of-stock-icon -->
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>

<product id="product-2">
    <thumbnail>
        <img>
        <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>

<product id="product-3">
    <thumbnail>
        <img>
        <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>
```

What I'm trying to do here, is find that one product element which has the out-of-stock icon inside it, and then decrease its thumbnail opacity. Here's what I'm thinking about:

```
if ($('product .out-of-stock-icon').length) {
  $('product thumbnail').css('opacity', '0.8');
}
```

What I'm trying to do (I don't know how to express this correctly):

```
for (x in product) {
  if (product[x].has('out-of-stock-icon') {
    product[x].itsThumbnail.setOpacity(0.8);
  }
}
```

And turns out to be, all products thumbnail are dimmed, not just the product I specified above. I know what wrong I've done, but I can't search for a right solution to fix this.

This is my very first question on stackoverflow. If I didn't do something right, please let me know. Sorry for my cringy English, and thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. None of the elements you're using are valid. You need to correct this. I've done so in the example below, but obviously this is making assumptions about your UI.

To solve the issue raised in your question you can use the `:has` selector

```js
$('.product:has(.out-of-stock-icon) .thumbnail').addClass('oos');
```

```css
.oos {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product" id="product-1">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img />
  </div>
  <div class="detail">In stock</div>
</div>

<div class="product" id="product-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img />
    <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">Out of stock</div>
</div>

<div class="product" id="product-3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img />
    <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">Out of stock</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why html isn't valid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Firstly, because the OP has done none of the required work to register the non-standard elements. Secondly, context because they state: `I'm new to HTML, CSS and Jquery`

Comment: It worked! I didn't know about :has selector in Jquery yet, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [jquery's `parent()` function](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). It gives you the first parent in the hierarchy matches a selector. So,

```js
$('product .out-of-stock-icon').parent('thumbnail').css('opacity', '0.8');
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I'll take a look at the parent() function to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check whether any item with class `out-of-stock-icon` exists inside the product or not.

```
$("product").each(function(){
  if($(this).find(".out-of-stock-icon").length)
    $(this).find("thumbnail").css("opacity", 0.2);
});
```

```js
$("product").each(function(){
  if($(this).find(".out-of-stock-icon").length)
    $(this).find("thumbnail").css("opacity", 0.2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<product id="product-1">
    <thumbnail>
      Product 1
        <img>
        <!-- This product does not have the out-of-stock-icon -->
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>

<product id="product-2">
    <thumbnail>
    Product 2
        <img>
        <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>

<product id="product-3">
    <thumbnail>
    Product 3
        <img>
        <span class="out-of-stock-icon"></span>
    </thumbnail>
    <detail></detail>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You need to use `parent()`(method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these elements in the DOM tree) and The `css` method sets or returns one or more style properties for the selected elements.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".out-of-stock-icon"));
    for(var i=0; i < elements.length;i++) {
        elements[i].parentNode.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
</script>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(".out-of-stock-icon").parent().css('opacity', 0.5);
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution worked too, I'll try to re-read and understand these methods, thank you!

Comment: @TranTam Thanks for replying and Happy... your issue was resolved. Thanks, too.